# Android JNI - return json string performance

Tags: java, android, c++, json, android-ndk

I work with Android JNI + NDK in the last month and i create two ways to return data from the c++ to java. The problem is i  don't really sure about the performance.

-) The first common way and the hardest, is to call the java object constructor from the JNI and return jobject.

-) The second way it to add toJson() function in the C++ class and return string representation of the class to java. the java class which catch the data parse it to object with Gson.

This operation will be call for 200 time in a second.

The question is headed to developers who already try it and can share its knowledge with me.(for those who mark it with -1 remember that stack overflow is here to share knowledge).
TY.

Comment: I found that facebook uses FlatBuffer instead of json, and they get better performance, like described here:
http://frogermcs.github.io/flatbuffers-in-android-introdution/

so while we still don't know the answer what is better json, or direct access, there is one more option with FlatBuffers

Comment: @Arkady Thanks. This looks very promising but unfortunately I don't work on this project any more so I can't test it out